# Difference in Differences Dummy Variable Generation

Tags: r, experimental-design

I am working on a project investigating the impact of network improvements. I would like to investigate a difference in differences approach, but I am not sure how to go about generating the dummy variable necessary to measure the treatment effect. My dataset looks something like the following:

[image]

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9), year = c(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2002, 2006, 
2009, 2010, 2006, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2006, 2007, 2006, 2010, 
2011, 2012), network = c(200, 250, 250, 250, 100, 400, 400, 220, 
105, 70, 135, 200, 102, 0, 0, 0, 50, 150, 150), treat = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

That is, my treatment variable is defined as 1 if for the same ID there was an increase in the network compared to the previous observed year and 0 otherwise. For example, for ID 2, the network increased between 2002 and 2006, so the treatment variable is 1. How do I go about creating this variable in R? I prefer tidyverse solutions if possible.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Grouped by 'id', get the difference between the 'network' and the `lag` of 'network' and check whether the difference is greater than 0, convert the `logical` from the comparison to binary with `+` or (`as.integer`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(treat2 =  +(network - lag(network, default = first(network)) > 0)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 19 × 5
      id  year network treat treat2
   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
 1     1  2002     200     0      0
 2     1  2003     250     1      1
 3     1  2004     250     0      0
 4     1  2005     250     0      0
 5     2  2002     100     0      0
 6     2  2006     400     1      1
 7     2  2009     400     0      0
 8     3  2010     220     0      0
 9     4  2006     105     0      0
10     5  2009      70     0      0
11     5  2010     135     1      1
12     5  2011     200     1      1
13     6  2012     102     0      0
14     7  2006       0     0      0
15     8  2007       0     0      0
16     9  2006       0     0      0
17     9  2010      50     1      1
18     9  2011     150     1      1
19     9  2012     150     0      0
```